# Z-Axis label cut off in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbHyn.png)

I've been trying to reformat the graph produced from this code so the Z-axis label is visible but nothing so far has worked. Does anyone have any insight? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import optimize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('flowDS_dat.csv')

X = [list(df.Diameter), list(df.Slope)]
Y = list(df.Flow)
def func(X, a0, a1, a2):
    return a0*(X[0]**a1)*(X[1]**a2)


popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, X, Y)

print('a0 = {}'.format('{:1.3f}'.format(popt[0])))
print('a1 = {}'.format('{:1.3f}'.format(popt[1])))
print('a2 = {}\n'.format('{:1.3f}'.format(popt[2])))
print(f'Final Equation: Q = {"{:1.3f}".format(popt[0])} * D^{"{:1.3f}".format(popt[1])} * S^{"{:1.3f}".format(popt[2])}\n')

x_vals = [2.5, 0.025]
Q = func(x_vals, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
print('Flow through the pipe with the given parameters is {} ft^3/s\n'.format('{:1.3f}'.format(Q)))


ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection = '3d')
ax.plot(X[0], X[1], Y)
plt.title('Flow vs. Slope vs. Diameter')
ax.set_xlabel('Diameter (ft)')
ax.set_ylabel('Slope (ft/ft)')
ax.set_zlabel('Flow (ft^3/s)')
```

I've used tight_fit, and I've played around with the sizing. Please, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It is a lot easier to help if you provide code that we can run.  In this case, I cannot run your code because I do not have your csv file.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example